# SQLite3 error: 'near "UP" : syntax error'?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to update a name column inside sqlite database on my C program using the following function:

```
void update_name(int row, wchar_t* name, int maxnamelen){
    const wchar_t* update_tempate = L"UPDATE mytable SET name='%s' WHERE(id=%d);";
    wchar_t* update = calloc(sizeof(wchar_t*), maxnamelen+wcslen(update_template));
    swprintf(update, update_template, name, row);
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3_prepare16(sqdb, update, sizeof(update), &stmt, 0);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

but I don't get the row updated unfortunately, because I get the error `near "UP" : syntax error`.

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: The first parameter to `calloc` should be `sizeof(wchar_t)`; and you forgot the zero terminator.

Comment: sizeof(wchar_t*) is correct, but the mistake is that I forgot the zero terminator.

Comment: `wchar_t*` is a pointer, but you want to allocate an array of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of `sqlite3_prepare16` must be the length of the statement, in bytes.

However, `sizeof(update)` is the size of the `update` variable, which is just a pointer, which happens to have the same size as two characters.

You have to give either the actual length (which was already computed by `swprintf`), or just -1.

---

Please note that this will still blow up when the name contains a quote.
You should use parameters to avoid such formatting problems:

```
void update_name(int row, wchar_t* name)
{
    const wchar_t* update = L"UPDATE mytable SET name=? WHERE id=?";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    // error handling is missing
    sqlite3_prepare16(sqdb, update, -1, &stmt, 0);
    sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 1, name, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, row);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```